# Rendering ViewGroup on Canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, canvas

I'm implementing a small library for easy adding custom view swiping actions on a RecyclerView. During my implementation I've hit a issue when rendering views on a canvas. I've attached a gif here to showcase the problem:

[image: Showcase]

When drawing the swipe view on the Canvas I do the follow:

```
    private fun renderSwipeView(
        view: View,
        c: Canvas,
        width: Int,
        height: Int,
        transX: Float,
        transY: Float
    ) {
        view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        )
        view.layout(0, 0, width, height)

        c.withTranslation(transX, transY) {
            view.draw(c)
        }
    }
```

This generally works fine, but I'm seeing issues rendering with view types. In the GIF i
The green layout is a square which is centered to the top of the layout. So I know the layout is rendered in the correct size and the layouting of elements is done correctly.

Issue 1:
The blue boxes are `TextView`'s with `singleLine=true` since I want the text to be neatly revealed by the element on top. Swipe right basically works fine, however on swipe left the text is not rendered at all. I tried to render this same case without rending it on a Canvas which works fine. Am I missing some part when rendering my view on the canvas?

Issue 2:
Not really a big problem, but the swipe view (red / orange container) will be rendered out side it's layout. I could easily fix this by using `canvas.clipRect()` on the canvas, but I would like to solve the root cause of this rather than do a workaround.

Entire source code with this demo can be seen [here](https://github.com/Rawa/recycler-swipes).

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Regarding issue 1: I just managed to first issue. It seems to be related to a bug in TextView, by switching to AppCompatTextView the issue was solved.